# error in adding cordova platform android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, platform

I have issues in adding platform android using  cordova command due to which i cannot be able to  build my ionic app

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific about your issues?

Comment: when i did "ionic serve" then program run the browser

Comment: bt when we "cordova plateforn it showing error i already send u screenshot"

Comment: i want build apk for android

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the project in other Drive instead of C: Drive